# Why is the "mit" used in front of the separable "ein" of "einplanen" in this sentence?

Tags: preposition, grammar-identification, separable-verb

I came across this example in a textbook:

> Planen Sie auch Stau oder Ähnliches mit ein.

The verb is clearly "einplanen". The meaning of the sentence can be understood easily. However, I wonder why there is a "mit" there.

Comment: There is also another verb: `miteinbeziehen`. The `mit` and `ein` are in general separable, while the `be` is non-separable.

Comment: Also see https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61264/die-war-sogar-mit-in-amerika

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a particle/separable prefix that is written separately from the rest of the word.

So "mit einplanen" has two parts it can separate: "mit" and "ein". When the verb is "disassembled" in your sentence structure, you keep finding them in this order: `Ich plane das mit ein.`.

For verbs for which permanent involvement/participation or union is expressed, it is written unseparated (in the sense of a spacing between them): `mitbringen, mitmachen, mitwirken, mitwollen,` usw.
But this is by far not always clear and you could argue, a question of interpretation. Some allow both writings: `mit berücksichtigen / mitberücksichtigen, mit unterzeichnen / mitunterzeichnen`.
Some that allow only separated writing are: `mit ansehen, mit übernehmen.`

So notably, "Hilf mir mit aufladen" and "Hilf mir mit dem Aufladen" don't use "mit" the same way.

Some examples for your understanding:

> Ich muss das Dokument mitunterzeichnen / mit unterzeichnen.
> Ich helfe, das Dokument mit zu unterzeichnen / mitzuunterzeichnen.
> Wie unterzeichne ich das Dokument mit?
> Sieh dir das mit an!
> Ich will es mit ansehen.

"Mit" is stressed.

Comment: Sollte der zweite Satz nicht sein "So "miteinplanen" has two parts it can separate..." or since I think it always has to be separated "So "mit einplanen" has two parts it can separate..."

Comment: @YanickSalzmann Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

"Mit" in this case probably isn't a preposition, but a prefix to the verb "einplanen". "Miteinplanen" seems a bit unwieldy at first glance, but the similar verb "mitberücksichtigen" has entries at [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mitberuecksichtigen) and [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/mitber%C3%BCcksichtigen). Both mention "mit berücksichtigen" as "verwandte Form" and "Nebenform", respectively. I would understand "miteinplanen" or "mit einplanen" in a similar fashion. DWDS has a seperate entry for [the prefix mit-](https://www.dwds.de/wb/mit-), and Duden lists the [similar prefix Mit-](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mit_) to use with nouns.

Answer (score 3):

*Mit* can be used as a prefix on top of another prefix. It is separated with a space when the other prefix is separated as well, and it may be separated with a space otherwise.

The meaning is roughly *also, as well*.

Comment: This is a pattern, but is it always true? It is also separated for mit übernehmen, which only has one prefix: "mit". Dudenband 9 only gives meaning-related advice to it. I don't think you can make a rule like this.

Comment: People write both *mit übernehmen* and *mitübernehmen*. The only rule you can state is that people don't combine *mit* and a separated prefix.

Comment: If what you said was true, then "miteinbeziehen" should not be listed in Duden as an alternative to "mit einbeziehen", both having the separable prefix "ein". DWDS also lists "miteinbeziehen".

Comment: You haven't understood what I have written. This is not about separable prefixes but about *separated* prefixes. So you can write *mit einbeziehen* and *miteinbeziehen* but not *Er bezieht es mitein.* but only *Er bezieht es mit ein.*